# How do i fix mysqli_expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result string given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When i try to execute the query and get the number of rows then and error is generated. I have been trying to fix this issue for days and i am new to php so it probably might not even be a syntax problem.

```
  <?php
  // error_reporting(0);

  $flying_from = "";
  $flying_to = "";
  $departure_date = "";
  $return_date = "";
  $number_of_adults = "";
  $number_of_children = "";
  $flight_class = "";

  // Connect to database
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'presh', '1234', 'saffron');

  if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $flying_from = $_GET['flying_from'];
    $flying_to = $_GET['flying_to'];
    $departure_date = $_GET['departure_date'];
    $return_date = $_GET['return_date'];
    $number_of_adults = $_GET['number_of_adults'];
    $number_of_children = $_GET['number_of_children'];
    $flight_class = $_GET['flight_class'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flying_from LIKE $flying_from AND flying_to LIKE $flying_to AND departure_date LIKE $departure_date AND return_date LIKE $return_date AND
    number_of_adults LIKE $number_of_adults AND number_of_children LIKE $number_of_children AND flight_class LIKE $flight_class";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0){
        $output = 'There was no search results';
    }else{
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fFrom = $row['flying_from'];
        $fTo = $row['flying_to'];
        $dDate = $row['departure_date'];
        $rDate = $row['return_date'];
        $nAdults = $row['number_of_adults'];
        $nChildren = $row['number_of_children'];
        $fClass = $row['flight_class'];

        $output .= '<div>'.$fFrom.' '.$fTo. ' '.$dDate.' '.$rDate.' '.$nAdults.' '.$nChildren.' '.$fClass.'</div>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to pass the `$result` variable not `$query` in `mysqli_fetch_array()`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

}
```